# Returning php div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class, return-type

I want to call the class "aa" twice and call it.

How to organize the following code for this?

```
    <?php
        $A2Gtr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_sayfalar WHERE kategori=3");
        while ($A2Oku = mysql_fetch_object($A2Gtr)) {
    ?>
    <div class="aa">          
        <div  style="height:160px; float: left;" class="genel">
            <div style="padding:15px;background-color:#F2ECD6; height:125px; float: left;"" class="resim">
                <a style="float: left;" href="index.php?Git=UrunDetay&id=<?php echo $A2Oku->id ?>">
                    <?php echo'<img src="Panel/Sayfalar/Bresimler/' . $A2Oku->bresim . '" width="220" height="130" alt="" />' ?>
                </a>
                <span style="margin-left:35px; position:absolute; width:385px; font-size:14px; color:#B43325; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; float: left" class="detay"><b><?php echo stripslashes(mb_substr($A2Oku->baslik, 0, 83, 'UTF8')) ?></b>
                    <br></br>
                    <span style="font-size:12px; color:#666; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
                        <?php echo stripslashes(mb_substr($A2Oku->baslik2, 0, 280, 'UTF8')) ?><a style="color:#CE0000;" href="index.php?Git=TurDetay&id=<?php echo $A2Oku->id ?>"><i>...Devamı</i></a></span>
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What does this mean? "I want to call the class "aa" twice and call it."

Comment: hii.. <div class="aa">Now all the data comes. i want Rotate aa twice

Answer (score 0):

It is?

```
// Your WHILE() +
$i = 0;
while($i < 2){
   $i++;
    // Your HTML code
}
```